# Debo usar hilos en un web service de php para android en java?

Tags: android, hilos, jwt, volley, asynctask

Voy a crear una app en android que creo que debe tener los siguientes requisitos
-La app la generaré en android usando java
-Se conectará mediante un crud web service php / mysql / volley
-Para aumentar la seguridad quiero usar JWT (json web token)
-¿Es necesario para insertar /actualizar / borrar datos en este web service que use hilos desde mi aplicación para evitar que no se incluyan los datos en "fila" según las peticiones al servidor? ¿O como o que tengo que implementar desde android para poder hacer esto?

Va a ser mi primera aplicación a nivel un poco mas profesional y quiero tenerlo todo controlado antes de comenzar a codificar.

He estado revisando por la web y mirando mucha información y cada vez estoy mas liado con que es mejor hacer y en que orden.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra colaboración
saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que las preguntas que requieren opiniones regularmente son cerradas en el sitio, revisar [ask], muestra lo que trataste o investigaste, saludos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score -1):

Android es muy puñetero con las llamadas via API que es lo que quieres realizar basicamente, si es la api esta echa en PHP, C#, nodejs, etc... eso da igual lo importante es que siempre estes esperando un JSON o un XML aunque yo te recomiendo un JSON.

Porque digo que Android es puñetero con las API's porque toda llamada externa que realices tiene que ser siempre asyncrona, hay que crear hilos y esperar el final del hilo. Si no lo haces de esta manera Android no te dejara compilar porque detecta que estas llamando a un WebService sin hacerlo asyncronamente.

Mi consejo hazte una clase general que le puedas pasarle rutas en diferentes metodos, **Get, POST, Delete, etc... **
Dicha clase que te devuelva cualquier objeto, esto se realiza de la siguietne manera

```
class HTTPRequest<T>{
  public T Api(string Url){
     //Mira como llamar a una Url deserializar el Json
     return Json.Deserialized<"La clase que deserializes>(json);
  }
}
```

A la clase al ponerle  no le estas diciendo que devuelva un modelo en concreto si no el que deserialize, de esta manera siempre te devolvera, o Usuarios, o Coches, o Perros o lo que sea.

Espero que te haya sacado de dudas. Pero sobre todo toda las llamadas que se hacen a urls son asyncronas si o si

Comment: Bueno, las prueba a nivel local que he hecho con el web service hecho en php para recibir datos en un json de la consulta a mysql, no he puesto hilos y funcionan, pero entiendo que a nivel de que esa app la use cada persona desde su teléfono, se debe usar un hilo para evitar "el que se pisen" al guardar datos por ejemplo entre un usuario y otro verdad? es esto a lo que me refiero